# Where can I direct download the NXT blockchain data instead of from the client?

Tags: blockchain, nxt

When installing the nxt nrs client from scratch I need to redownload the nxt_db database blockchain. Is there a place where I can just download it from directly on a fast connection? It seems that it takes at least 3+ hours to download the nxt blockchain from other peers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to http://www.peerexplorer.com.
2. Click on the orange link at the bottom of the page: "Download Nxt Blockchain"
3. In the pop-up window, click on the "Mirror 1" link. This takes you to dropbox.com.
4. Click on "Download". You can skip registration.